# How to stop a running script in JavaScriptCore (iOS)

Tags: ios, javascriptcore

I'm using JavaScriptCore in my iOS app to let users run scripts. The user potentially can create a script that runs too long or infinitely. I want to be able to cancel a running script either in response to user actions or after X sec. What would be a proper way to do it?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm looking for a solution to this also.